# Show loading-message in another div when waiting for jquery ajax load

Tags: jquery

The following code loads the page-handler.php into #page when the function load is fired and while waiting shows ajax_load. How can I make the ajax_load loding-message show in another div and of course disappear when the loding is finished?

```
function load(value) {
    $('#page').html(ajax_load);
    $("#page").load("page-handler.php", {page:value});
    return false;
}
```

Comment: wow everybody gave the same answer in less than a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function load(value) {
    $('somediv').html(ajax_load);
    $("#page").load("page-handler.php", {page:value}, function() {
      $('somediv').empty(); // or set new contents, or hide, or whatever
    });
    return false;
}
```

This will put the contents into whatever has the id 'somediv'. You can use a class (`'.class'`) or several other [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to choose your div.

Comment: all type of solutions this far works, you were first with the solution I ended up using, thanks

Comment: @Joseph - look and Vincent's answer, please :)

Answer (score 2):

You start by creating a hidden div with the loading message:

```
 <div id="loading">loading...</div>
```

Then in your function:

```
function load(value) {
    $('#loading').show();
    $('#page').html(ajax_load);
    $("#page").load("page-handler.php", {page:value}, function(){
            $('#loading').hide();
    });
    return false;
}
```

of course you have to do something about if the ajax call did not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using $('#selector').ajaxStart() and $('#selector').ajaxStop();

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

Answer (score 0):

Show a div before starting your call and hide it in a callback, e.g.:

```
function load(value) {
    $('#busydiv').show(); // shows busy indicator
    $('#page').html(ajax_load);
    $("#page").load("page-handler.php", {page:value}, function() {
         $('#busydiv').hide();
    });
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think this is what you want?

```
$("#anotherDiv").html(message);
$("#page").load("page-handler.php", {page:value}, function(){$("#anotherDiv").hide();});
```

That will hide the other div when ajax loads.